# Branch Policy with path restrictions in Azure DevOps

Tags: git, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task

Let's say my repository has three directories as shown below:

- a/

  - file1.txt
  - file2.txt
  - file3.txt
- b/

  - file1.txt
  - file2.txt
- c/

  - file4.txt
  - file5.txt

I want to create a policy such that if any of the files in directory `a` are touched, no changes in other directories (`b` and `c`) should be allowed in the same pull request. In other words, to change any files in directory `a`, the user must create a new PR and can't combine the changes with `b` and `c` files.
There are no such restrictions on the directories `b` and `c`. That is, a user may choose to update files in `b` alone, `c` alone or combine updates to files in `b` and `c` in one PR.

Is this something that can be configured in Azure DevOps? I went through the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/branch-policies?view=azure-devops) and FAQs but didn't find anything helpful.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is probably most easily enforced using your CI system.

Comment: I see this more of git rather than a DevOps, you can run a `pre-commit` hook script as part of the project and not allow users to commit such changes.

Answer (score 1):

Azure DevOps do not support git server-side pre-commit hooks, but there is an [open Feature Request](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/365841/add-git-pre-receive-hooks.html) about it.

So to achieve your goal, you can add a [build validation policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/branch-policies?view=azure-devops#build-validation) to your PR, in this build add a PowerShell script that checks the PR commits (with [Rest API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pull%20requests/get%20pull%20request?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1)) and fail the build if there are changes in 2 folders.